# Send a string with white space through socket tcp

Tags: c, sockets, getline

I'm trying to send, from a client to a server, a whole line, which is read from the bash.

Client:

```
char buf[200];
int line_len;
getline(&buf, &line_len, stdin);
printf("Sending: %s", buf);
sendl(tcp_sock, buf);
```

Server:

```
char app[200];
recvl(client, app);
printf("\n%s\n", app);
```

Sendl and recvl are function defined by me that actually send and recv, working 100%

The issue is on the `getline`, which works not correctly. 
When i print `Sending: %s` after have typed "hello banana" i always get strange char like `��` that here i cannot even display..

Can you help me?

EDIT: working now thanks to @dbush

Comment: How do you know `getline` is not working correctly?  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: `getline` returns the number of characters read. You can check the no. of characters returned and cross-verify with the line length you want to send to the server.

Comment: done sorry, i hope now it's pretty good

Comment: @kiner_shah i can even verify, anyway the characters read are totally different from the one i typed. so???

Comment: What about `line_len`? Tried printing that? And what about `buf` before getline?

Comment: This is still not a [mcve].  Please show the definition of all relevant variables, particularly `buf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getline` function expects a `char **` for its first argument.  You're instead passing in a `char [200]` which decays to a `char *`.  These types are incompatible, and your compiler should have warned you about this.

You need to pass the address of a pointer variable for the first argument.  This pointer should be initialized to `NULL` and `linelen` should be initialized to 0.  `getline` will then allocate memory for the line that was read.  When you're done with this buffer, you should `free` it:

```
char *buf = NULL;
int line_len = 0;
getline(&buf, &line_len, stdin);
buf[line_len] = '\0';
printf("Sending: %s", buf);
sendl(tcp_sock, buf);
free(buf);
```

Comment: Perfectly working if modifying into `getline(&buf, &line_len, stdin);` . Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ducajack For "Perfect", code should check the return value of `getline()`.

Comment: dbush: Why `buf[line_len] = '\0';`? Seems unnecessary.